# How to run 3 commands in one line in a docker

Tags: linux, git, docker, linux-containers

I try to run this command but i always get the [message](https://pastebin.com/i8BB180f)

`/bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/lordLegal/Test-repo.git; pip3 install urllib3 ; python3 -u /Test-repo/while.py`

I also tryed the same thing with `&&` instead of the `;` in the command
but i got the same message

So my Question is how can I fix it?

btw I try this on a docker container from alpine

Comment: `I try to run this command` There is no `docker` even in that command. Maybe try adding `docker` in front of it first? What __exactly__ do you run in your terminal?

Comment: I suppose you should wrap commands after the `-c` with quotes

Comment: Yes thank you @NobbyNobbs for the Help it worked

Comment: (Of those three commands, you should run `git clone` directly on your host; `RUN pip install` in the Dockerfile; and set the image's `CMD ./while.py` also in the Dockerfile.  They do three different things and wouldn't usually go in the same line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put arguments between `"`, so your command should look like this:

```
/bin/sh -c "git clone https://github.com/lordLegal/Test-repo.git; pip3 install urllib3 ; python3 -u /Test-repo/while.py"
```